# Pass variable from mainwindow to another qt c++ forms

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I want to pass three strings (cellTitle,cellPoem,cellGroup) from mainwindows to another dialog. I know when i initiate the second form the values become zeros. I read somewhere it's possible with slots but i don't know how.

mainwindows.h

```
public:
QString cellTitle,cellPoem,cellGroup;
```

mainwindows.cpp

```
void MainWindow::on_tableView_pressed(const QModelIndex &index)

{

    cellText = ui->tableView->model()->data(index).toString();



    QSqlQuery * qry2 = new QSqlQuery(mydb);

    qry2->prepare("select * from Poems where Title='"+cellText+"'");
    qry2->exec();


    while(qry2->next()){

    cellTitle = qry2->value(1).toString();
    cellPoem = qry2->value(2).toString();
    cellGroup = qry2->value(3).toString();



    ui->textEdit->setText(qry2->value(2).toString());

 }
```

}

```
void MainWindow::on_btnUpdate_clicked()

{

   frmUpdate frmupdate;
   frmupdate.setModal(true);
   frmupdate.exec();

}
```

frmupdate.cpp

```
#include "frmupdate.h"

#include "ui_frmupdate.h"
#include <mainwindow.h>

frmUpdate::frmUpdate(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::frmUpdate)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    MainWindow mainwindow;

    ui->lineEdit->setText(mainwindow.cellTitle);
    ui->lineEdit_2->setText(mainwindow.cellGroup);
    ui->textEdit->setText(mainwindow.cellPoem);
}

frmUpdate::~frmUpdate()
{
    delete ui;
}

void frmUpdate::on_btnUpdate_clicked()
{


}

void frmUpdate::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    this->close();
}
```

Comment: Pass these strings in the constructor of `frmUpdate` as an arguments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing three QString from mainwindows to other dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51573974/passing-three-qstring-from-mainwindows-to-other-dialog)

Comment: You have more than 2 years in SO and you should know that publishing several post with the same question is not appropriate, what you should do is improve your post showing your progress, gain reputation and maybe give a bounty, or before publishing this new question you should eliminate the previous one and not point it out. On the other hand 10 hours is little considering that we are on a weekend

Comment: @eyllanesc Sorry for inconvenient. I just delete the old post.

Comment: you ask for an answer in 10 hours, so I ask myself: What have you advanced in 10 hours?

Comment: @Mohit could you explain more please.

Comment: I just make it. Thanks .Should i put the code here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
frmUpdate::frmUpdate(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::frmUpdate)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    MainWindow mainwindow;
```

You here have created a  *new, temporary* `MainWindow` instance only with default constructor being called. Of course, this new instance is then created with empty default texts:

```
    ui->lineEdit->setText(mainwindow.cellTitle);
    ui->lineEdit_2->setText(mainwindow.cellGroup);
    ui->textEdit->setText(mainwindow.cellPoem);
}
```

Easiest now would be passing the *original* main window as parameter:

```
frmUpdate::frmUpdate(QWidget* parent, MainWindow* mainWindow) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::frmUpdate)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->lineEdit->setText(mainwindow->cellTitle);
    ui->lineEdit_2->setText(mainwindow->cellGroup);
    ui->textEdit->setText(mainwindow->cellPoem);
}
```

*If* the parent *is* the main window, you can simply cast:

```
frmUpdate::frmUpdate(QWidget* parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::frmUpdate)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    MainWindow* mainWindow = qobject_cast<MainWindow*>(parent);
    if(mainWindow)
    {
        ui->lineEdit->setText(mainwindow->cellTitle);
        ui->lineEdit_2->setText(mainwindow->cellGroup);
        ui->textEdit->setText(mainwindow->cellPoem);
    }
    else
    {
        // appropriate error handling
    }
}
```

You might search the main window from parent as well:

```
for(;;)
{
    MainWindow* mainWindow = qobject_cast<MainWindow*>(parent);
    if(mainWindow)
    {
        ui->lineEdit->setText(mainwindow->cellTitle);
        ui->lineEdit_2->setText(mainwindow->cellGroup);
        ui->textEdit->setText(mainwindow->cellPoem);
        break;
    }
    parent = parent->parent();
    if(!parent)
    {
        // appropriate error handling
        break;
    }
}
```

All above assuming that `MainWindow` inherits from `QObject`...

Comment: ُThanks for your help.